Redundant byte offset requirement in the Contract ABI Specification?
I've had the pleasure of finding out that, contrary to what I've been used to in the other byte-transferring/-interpretation systems (e.g. the C/C++ languages, the communication protocols, etc.), calling a smart contract function expecting an array (say, an uint[]) would mean forming the tx.data field of your transaction as follows:

The function selector,
The byte offset at which the encoding of the array starts (in this case, the offset would point at the location of 3.),
The length of the array,
The items of the array.

What's the reasoning behind the Smart Contract ABI Specification's requirement to prepend the  array argument with not just the length of the array, but, also, with the byte offset (wrt the beginning of the encoding of the array) at which the array length and its contents/items can be found?
While I understand why prepending the array contents with its length is important (without this, in a function that expects 2 consecutive arrays of the same type - say, f(uint[] arr1, uint[] arr2) it'd be impossible to determine where the first array ends - and the second one begins), I can't say the same about the byte offset.
Can you think of a simple example that would demonstrate why having the byte offset is not redundant (as, for example, it is redundant in the f(uint[] arr1, uint[] arr2) example above...)?

One of the factors is efficiency.

The abi decoder is embedded in every contract, so it should be as small as possible.
Minimize runtime execution. Every bytecode has a cost skip decoding unnecessary parameters.

If there were only fixed size types in solidity it would have been easy to calculate a parameter starting offset within calldata without decoding.
The ABI define that types with variable size should set its offset instead of its value.
Note: A more complex decoder could have been defined inside the EVM as a new opcode, but it would have taken considerable time and resources to have it ready on time.

You're talking about skipping the decoding of the unused function arguments, right? I don't see why the same decoding efficiency couldn't be achieved if the tx.data args of Dynamic Types contains just their length and items (w/o the extra byte offset). If you want to, e.g., skip the unused uint[] argument, look at its length - and go straight to the next function argument by jumping length * sizeof(uint) bytes ahead.

Give a paramter k you have to calculate how much skip for every of the k -1 previous parameters. For fixed size parameter it is easy sum size_of(param) can be calculated at compile time. For every dynamic parameter you have to read its size at run time, and calculate their sum. It is doable, and probably quite cheap for modern processor, but for the EVM it is an extra computation.

Oh... So, you're referring to the cases when, say, the first 2 function args are unused - and you need to access the 3rd one. I do see how having the offset of the 3rd arg would help jump to it directly, w/o losing any resources on the unused args. However, this all feels like optimizing for the bad code (with functions that don't use their args), while the clean code runtime performance suffers (unjustly). It should be the exact opposite, imo.

You are right, the decisions taken during Ethereum development are a compromise. The EVM is generic enough that anyone can develop and propose an alternative ABI.

Ok, so, we agree that it's unclear why the current ABI Specification requires the byte offset alongside the dynamic type length of the function argument, given that it seems to only be justified when the code isn't of the best quality (i.e. there are unused function args) in the first place. However, I believe that there must be an explanation for this, and we should keep digging in order to, hopefully, get to it :)
